# Publish Option Missing or Name Changed?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

I am going through the following tutorial on bot framework

http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/#getting-started-in-net

According to the tutorial I should select "Microsoft Azure App Service" as my publish target:
[image]

But I am not seeing that option in my publish options:
[image]

Did something change name-wise or am I missing something in my IDE?
I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did you work this out? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft Azure Web Apps option.

Answer (score 0):

The difference should be caused by that you are not updating to Azure SDK 2.8.1 or later, I'd like to suggest you check on that. In Azure SDK 2.8.1, Microsoft re-designed the entire App Service tooling and introduced a new modern App Service creation experience  to unifying the app creation and publishing experiences for Web, Mobile, and API app. Check detailed information in [Azure SDK 2.8.1 announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/blog/announcing-azure-sdk-2-8-1-for-net/).

So if you want to be exact the same with the demo, please try update Azure SDK to 2.8.1 or later. Or just using the corresponding target you are trying to publish to. Hope this helps.